# Gtk Error makes pointer from integer without a cast

Tags: c, gtk, gtksourceview

I'm try to create a simple ide and i'm got this error  !! 
when i compile the code i found this errors

```
gcc -c editor.c -Werror -g `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0 gtksourceview-3.0` `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0 gtksourceview-3.0`
editor.c: In function ‘editor_create’:
editor.c:40:10: error: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Werror]
buffer  = gtk_source_buffer_new (NULL);
      ^
editor.c:41:10: error: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Werror]
langm   = gtk_source_language_manager_new ();
      ^
editor.c:42:7: error: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Werror]
lang = gtk_source_language_manager_get_language (langm,"c");
   ^
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
Makefile:31: recipe for target 'editor.o' failed
make: *** [editor.o] Error 1
```

this is my function that i created please someone help me

```
#include "editor.h"
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <gtksourceview/gtksourceview.h>

ditor * editor_create(CSIde_app *app){
GtkSourceBuffer *buffer;
GtkSourceLanguage   *lang;
GtkSourceLanguageManager *langm;

Editor *editor  = (Editor*) g_slice_new(Editor);

editor->scrolled_window = gtk_scrolled_window_new (NULL,NULL);
gtk_scrolled_window_set_policy (GTK_SCROLLED_WINDOW(editor->scrolled_window ),GTK_POLICY_AUTOMATIC,GTK_POLICY_AUTOMATIC);

buffer  = gtk_source_buffer_new (NULL);
langm   = gtk_source_language_manager_new ();
lang    = gtk_source_language_manager_get_language (langm,"c");
editor->buffer = buffer;
editor->source_view = gtk_source_view_new_with_buffer (buffer);
gtk_source_view_set_auto_indent (GTK_SOURCE_VIEW(editor->source_view),TRUE);
gtk_source_view_set_show_line_numbers (GTK_SOURCE_VIEW(editor->source_view),TRUE);
gtk_source_buffer_set_language (buffer,lang);

gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER(editor->scrolled_window),editor->source_view);

return editor;
}
```

what's the probleme and how i can resolve it

Comment: The usual reason for "makes pointer from integer without a cast" is a missing prototype. Check that you have included the required header files. In this case for the function `gtk_source_buffer_new `.

Comment: I was already include all gtk ang gtksourceview headers

Comment: Show us the `#include` statement

Comment: I add the includes that I include them in `editor.h`